# Shift operation returning weird error

Tags: automation, plc, codesys, structured-text

I'm programming a plc by ABB in the codesys environment, and I can't figure out why I'm getting this error:

```
Error 4024: ... Expecting ELSIF,  ELSE or END_IF before 'SHL'
```

The code returning this error is something like:

```
IF flag THEN
    iState := 0;
    Step := false;
    SHL(1,iReg);
END_IF
```

Basically two assignments and a shift left operation on an unsigned integer. The shift is what gives the error, and commenting the line eliminates it.

I've checked the syntax many times, also inverted the arguments a few times following contradicting documentation.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your SHL needs to have a result

```
IF flag THEN
    iState := 0;
    Step := false;
    result := SHL(1,iReg);
END_IF
```

Comment: Oh thank you, it works perfectly now. Just an observation... I got the inputs mixed: first the variable to be shifted, then the number of positions

Comment: Yep, the SHL function returns a value. You need to tell the compiler where it goes.